# What is the indexing logic in the ImageData array?

Tags: javascript, binary, html5-canvas, typed-arrays, imagedata

This question is for a deeper understanding of my previous question about large size Canvas animation. The question is here: [Repeat HTML canvas element (box) to fill whole viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65340502/repeat-html-canvas-element-box-to-fill-whole-viewport)

I am trying to understand the logic behind the TypedArray - Uint8ClampedArray. I will first start with my research and get to the question itself later.

So, ImageData represents the pixel data of the HTML5 Canvas. It allows for much faster performance and is good for heavy animations. After we have our ImageData object, we create a buffer space for it. Because we can not read & write directly from / to buffer, we pass this buffer to a TypedArray. In this case Uint8ClampedArray which is like a normal array and allows to access data inside it.

Each pixel on our canvas is represented by 4 integer values that stand for red, green, blue, alfa - as in RGBA - ranging from 0 to 255. Each of these value is assigned to an Uint8ClampedArray index starting from 0 and the array is divided into chunks of 4. So first 4 values are very first pixel, second 4 values are 2nd pixel and so on. The Cavnas pixels are being read from left to right, row by row.

So if for example we want to get array index of red value of the pixel at `xCoord = 3; yCoord = 1; canvasWidth = 10;`. The formula from [MDN: Pixel manipulation with canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas) suggests that we do the following math:

`var red = y * (width * 4) + x * 4;` = 1 * 10 * 4 + 3 * 4 = 52;

But if we try to do the same manually, and just calculate ourselves pixel by pixel, we don't get the same value. It's always a little off. How would we calculate manually? In this picture we start from `0 X 0` to `0 X 9` and to `1 X 3`. Because we start from top left and move toward right, it's inverted and  **Y** is our first coordinate and **X** is our second coordinate. From `0 X 0` to `0 X 9` we record 40 values in total (4 values on each pixel, 10 pixels in total width); From `1 X 0` to `1 X 3` we record 16 values in total. We get 56th index at the end, instead of 52 as we had calculated using the formula.

So, please help me understand the whole logic in Uint8ClampedArray and how it's calcualted.

[image]

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45969661/6243352) is a nice canonical resource for working with this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From 1 X 0 to 1 X 3 we record 16 values in total

The last 4 bytes of these 16 do represent the pixel at (3, 1). The red channel is the first of these, preceded by 12 bytes for the pixels to the left and 40 bytes for the pixels in the first row. It is sitting at index 52 in the overall array.

Remember that [arrays are indexed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/110804/66652) as

```
0   1   2
+---+---+--
|   |   |
+---+---+--
```

not as

```
+---+---+--
| 0 | 1 | 2
+---+---+--
```

Comment: In other words, the pixel at coords 3,1 spans from indice 52 to 55, and because Arrays are 0 indexed, the 56th value is at index 55 -> their method gets the end index of the pixel, MDN's gets the start index. And btw for OP, a clearer way to write MDN's formula would be `((y * width) + x) * 4` -> pixel index * bytes per pixel